# Springboot health check request is held up by @RequestMapping(value="/**")

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

Our Code have to use `@RequestMapping(value="/**")`, which hold up the request `http：//localhost：8080/actuator/health`, and we are not able to return the health check result because of that.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For handlerMappings process flow, in DispatcherServlet.

```
    /**
     * Initialize the HandlerMappings used by this class.
     * <p>If no HandlerMapping beans are defined in the BeanFactory for this namespace,
     * we default to BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.
     */
    private void initHandlerMappings(ApplicationContext context) {
        this.handlerMappings = null;

        if (this.detectAllHandlerMappings) {
            // Find all HandlerMappings in the ApplicationContext, including ancestor contexts.
            Map<String, HandlerMapping> matchingBeans =
                    BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(context, HandlerMapping.class, true, false);
            if (!matchingBeans.isEmpty()) {
                this.handlerMappings = new ArrayList<>(matchingBeans.values());
                // We keep HandlerMappings in sorted order.
                AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(this.handlerMappings);
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                HandlerMapping hm = context.getBean(HANDLER_MAPPING_BEAN_NAME, HandlerMapping.class);
                this.handlerMappings = Collections.singletonList(hm);
            }
            catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
                // Ignore, we'll add a default HandlerMapping later.
            }
        }

        // Ensure we have at least one HandlerMapping, by registering
        // a default HandlerMapping if no other mappings are found.
        if (this.handlerMappings == null) {
            this.handlerMappings = getDefaultStrategies(context, HandlerMapping.class);
            if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                logger.trace("No HandlerMappings declared for servlet '" + getServletName() +
                        "': using default strategies from DispatcherServlet.properties");
            }
        }
    }
```

Pay attention to this line `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(this.handlerMappings);`

```
    /**
     * Return the HandlerExecutionChain for this request.
     * <p>Tries all handler mappings in order.
     * @param request current HTTP request
     * @return the HandlerExecutionChain, or {@code null} if no handler could be found
     */
    @Nullable
    protected HandlerExecutionChain getHandler(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        if (this.handlerMappings != null) {
            for (HandlerMapping mapping : this.handlerMappings) {
                HandlerExecutionChain handler = mapping.getHandler(request);
                if (handler != null) {
                    return handler;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Each handlerMapping has it`s own order, and you can set the order by `setOrder` or `@Order` etc.

```
    /**
     * This implementation checks for {@link Order @Order} or
     * {@link javax.annotation.Priority @Priority} on various kinds of
     * elements, in addition to the {@link org.springframework.core.Ordered}
     * check in the superclass.
     */
    @Override
    @Nullable
    protected Integer findOrder(Object obj) {
        // Check for regular Ordered interface
        Integer order = super.findOrder(obj);
        if (order != null) {
            return order;
        }

        // Check for @Order and @Priority on various kinds of elements
        if (obj instanceof Class) {
            return OrderUtils.getOrder((Class<?>) obj);
        }
        else if (obj instanceof Method) {
            Order ann = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation((Method) obj, Order.class);
            if (ann != null) {
                return ann.value();
            }
        }
        else if (obj instanceof AnnotatedElement) {
            Order ann = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation((AnnotatedElement) obj, Order.class);
            if (ann != null) {
                return ann.value();
            }
        }
        else {
            order = OrderUtils.getOrder(obj.getClass());
            if (order == null && obj instanceof DecoratingProxy) {
                order = OrderUtils.getOrder(((DecoratingProxy) obj).getDecoratedClass());
            }
        }

        return order;
    }
```